# How to avoid n + 1 without using includes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, join

I have two models

```
class Task < AR::Base
  habtm :user_groups
end

class UserGroup < AR::Base
  habtm :tasks
end
```

**Requirement:**

```
t = Task.where(id: 45734)
t.user_group_ids #[54, 523, 78]
```

The above line will cause 2 queries.

I want to do this in one query without using `includes`.

My Attempt:

```
tasks = Task.joins(:user_groups).select('tasks.id, user_groups.id as ug_id').where(customer_id: 5)
```

But it is retrieving only single user group even for the tasks which has multiple groups associated.

**Update**

As Max suggested:

```
t = Task.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN tasks_user_groups ON tasks_user_groups . analysis_task_id  =  tasks . id  INNER JOIN  user_groups  ON  user_groups . id  =  tasks_user_groups . user_group_id').select('user_groups.id').where(id: 36299)
```

Now i'm getting two tasks which has the same id but two different user groups.

Please suggest how to achieve it.

Comment: why don't you want to want to use `includes`?

Comment: Because `includes` takes more processing time when there is a huge data. You must know that `includes` brings up unnecessary data as well. Also recommended in the rails guides to use `joins` over `includes`

Answer (score 0):

`.joins` uses an `INNER LEFT JOIN` so it will only give the rows from tasks that have a match in `users_groups`.

`.includes` gets around this by using two separate queries.

What you want is instead is an outer join.

```
# Rails 5
Task.left_outer_joins(:user_groups)

# Rails 4
tasks = Task.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN user_groups ON user_groups.task_id = tasks.id')
```

See:

[What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join)

Comment: I'm getting `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column user_groups.task_id does not exist`

Comment: Its a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association which has a third join table called as `tasks_user_groups` with columns `analysis_task_id`, `user_group_id`

Comment: I was just guessing what your schema is. You can get the correct join string by running `Task.joins(:user_groups)` in the console and replacing the INNER keyword with OUTER.